# I need MYSQL query to represent check-in check-out log

Tags: mysql

Being a fresher in query writing, I need help at this MySQL scenario.My table has below records:

```
event_time     status          
  10:01          ON
  10:02          ON
  10:03          OFF
  10:04          ON
  10:07          OFF
  10:08          ON
  10:09          ON
  10:11          ON
  10:15          OFF
```

I want to print record as

```
 log_in       log_out      onCount          
  10:01        10:03         2
  10:04        10:07         1
  10:08        10:15         3
```

Any Suggestion.... ?? or code to get this result set

Comment: Events (in a day) always start with ON and end in OFF or is there a possibility this may not be true?

Comment: Also please add your MySQL version.